# xml dtd - what does + quantifier applies towards in this element?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, dtd

So - I've got this declaration in my .dtd file:

```
<!ELEMENT some_node1 (some_node2?, 
                      some_node3, 
                      (some_node4 | some_node5)*)+>
```

What does `+` means in here?

a) that `some_node2?, some_node3, (some_node4 | some_node5)*` sequence can be repeated 1 or more times?

b) that individual elements in parenthesis can be repeated 1 or more times?, ie some_node3,some_node3,some_node3,some_node3, some_node5, some_node5  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation you label 'a' is the correct one:  the sequence can occur one or more times.

The example you give under 'b', however, remains legal:  the sequence < some_node3, some_node3, some_node3, some_node3, some_node5, some_node5 > can be constructed by concatenating four occurrences of the sequence given in the content model:

1. `some_node3` (zero occurrences of some_node2, followed by one occurrence of some_node3, followed by zero occurrences of the choice between some_node4 and some_node5).
2. `some_node3` (see above)
3. `some_node3, some_node5, some_node5` (zero occurrences of some_node2, followed by exactly one occurrence of some_node3, followed by two occurrences of the choice between some_node4 and some_node5).

An example of a sequence that would be allowed under your interpretation 'b' (if I have understood it correctly) but not under 'a' (and not by the XML spec) is some_node2, some_node2, some_node3.